# Existence of solutions to time-dependent Schrödinger equations

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, operator-theory, schrodinger-operators

I would like to know what is known about evolution equations of the form

$$iy'(t)=H_0y(x,t)+u(t)V(x)y(x,t)$$
and $y(0)=y_0 \in D(H_0)$
where 
$V$ is not a bounded operator, but an unbounded one, $u \in C([0,T])$, and $H_0$ self-adjoint.

If $V$ is bounded, then one would obtain a solution preserving the domain of $H_0$ basically by Duhamel's formula. That situation is really standard.

However, I am not so sure what can be said in the case of unbounded $V.$ There seem to be a few really unpleasant domain problems that arise in this case. Obviously, $V$ cannot be completely arbitrary, but should maybe satisfy something like relative boundedness with respect to $H_0.$ At least, this would be my first guess.

Is there a paper or a book that discusses this situation in detail? I suppose since this equation has been studied a lot that this theory is well-developed.

Comment: I'd look at work of K. Yajima ([1991](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1243098), [2011](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2836569), [2016](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3543179)).